# what does the highlighted parts stand for?

Tags: ffmpeg

I run the command and I see a lot of data print out:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
```

The data looks like properties of the `input.mp4`. I was wondering what do the highlighted properties stand for. What do they mean?

[Output of the command `ffmpeg -i input.mp4`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz6wG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitrate describes the rate at which bits are transferred from one location to another in a given amount of time. Bitrate is commonly measured in bits per second (**bps**), kilobits per second (**Kbps**), or megabits per second (**Mbps**).

Bitrate can also describe the quality of an audio or video file. For example, an **MP3** audio file that is compressed at `192 Kbps` will have a greater dynamic range and may sound slightly more clear than the same audio file compressed at `128 Kbps`. This is because more bits are used to represent the audio data for each second of playback.

For further reading about [Bitrate](https://techterms.com/definition/bitrate).

Answer (score 0):

This videos image stream has an (average?) bitrate of 1212Kb/s,
and its audio stream has 128Kb/s.

This means, **1 second** of this .mp4 file takes (in theory) 1212 + 128 = **1340 Kb** to store on disk.

Comment: Thanks that answered my question.

Comment: @NetKenny Actually that not what `Bitrate` means.